# "input string was not in a correct format" DroidExplorer Desktop

Tags: windows, droid-explorer

I have never been able to load the application, this messages appears in a popup when i try and open it. Any help would be great.[image]

Comment: It would probably be best to click the "Report Bug" button and describe what happened.

Comment: This is more suitable as a bug report. I am out of town and have very limited computer access. But my initial thought is it has to do with the versions of the platforms downloaded with the SDK. There as a time that one of the platform names did not follow their own standard. You could try to remove the platforms by deleting all the folders in the SDK platforms folder. Then add the platforms again.

Comment: Hey All thanks for the replies. I downloaded and installed the SDK today not sure if that makes any difference. I tried the report a bug link and i have updated the bug tracker for the project as someone else reported a similar issue. I can dump any log files or do anything that would help track this down. Have a nice weekend !

Comment: I have added a comment/question to the bug. Once I get that information, I may be able to provide a "work around" here, and then a fix in code later.

Comment: Cool. Done _________

Comment: I think i found some more information that may lead to me being able to fix this. I have added another question to [the bug](https://de.codeplex.com/workitem/17420) if someone could provide information, it would help.